# How To Get Block CSS Style Sheet On Page Load Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

[image]I want to block style sheet on my page load event. e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   ## Here i want to block style sheet that is load in he ##
   ## <link rel="styleshtte" href="style.css"> ##
   ## How ti will possible ##

});
```

Comment: What you mean by block style sheet?

Comment: If you remove it the styles won't apply.

Comment: add `$('link').remove()`, quite rough but effective. If you want to selectively remove a stylesheet, add an id to the `<link>` you want to remove, and change jquery selector.

Comment: I mean that there are a number of css load when a page is render in that case i want to hide the single style sheet from the multiple styles sheet. Then how it will possible...As you know that in MVC structur we only work on the View and we define header already...Now I Attach The Example Please Check

Answer (score 1):

If you know the URL, just remove it.

```
$('link[href="link/to/css"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet.disabled) the stylesheet in question via javascript:

```js
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
```

Of course, you'd need to ensure you're disabling the correct stylesheet.

I'm not sure what browser support will be like with this, but it is working in `Chromium 39`.